# Format description in ColdFusion generated rss feed

Tags: xml, xslt, coldfusion, rss, coldfusion-8

Since `cffeed` writes everything out to XML, I'm not sure how to format the text in the description of my feed.  Ideally, I would like to be able to format the description as a list.  HTML characters are escaped and HTML special characters just show up as text.

Comment: What have you tried?  I haven't used CFFeed specifically, but I'm a little surprised that it isn't handling HTML correctly, as per the RSS standard

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  You're completely right.  I had the description wrapped in an XMLFormat() function that escaped all HTML chars.  Once I removed that, the feed handled the HTML just fine.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: :) Sometimes ColdFusion makes it so simple that we try to over complicate things

Answer (score 1):

> Wow, I'm an idiot. You're completely right. I had the description wrapped in an XMLFormat() function that escaped all HTML chars. Once I removed that, the feed handled the HTML just fine. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out why *you* added this as an answer. I believe the OP should do this, not someone else. But you could add an intro to make it clear you added it for him, and mark this post as community wiki too.

Comment: @bfavaretto I'll direct a comment to the OP. I didn't know how or why a community wiki was created. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: if you edit your answer, there is a community wiki checkbox. One of the effects of marking a post [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) is, if it is up/downvote, it won't affect your reputation. Seems fair in this case, since the content you posted was authored by the OP.

Comment: @user1451502 I added your comment as an answer.

Comment: @bfavaretto Done. I appreciate your explanation of the community wiki. I'll use that in situations like this going forward.